# How to set AzureFirewall to make my vm can connect Azure

Tags: azure

For connecting Azure ,how to set "from,to and port,etc" of AzureFirewall.
For example,*Connect-AzAccount* can connect Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Connect-AzAccount connects to the active directory tenant via port 443.
On whatever resource have you applied the firewall, the source IP would be yours, destination Ip would be the resource IP and same for the port. eg 443 for sql server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set the network rule From:MyVMIP, To:*, Port:80,443.It works. But I think "*" is not safe . Could you tell me something about resource IP.At least,i can connect Azure and run AzureComputeServices.